# Multiple IF statements in Python in a for loop or while loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

Let's say I buy a certain volume of petrol at price X, which is usually sold within a 30 days. During these 30 days, I will need to adjust my petrol station gas price according to average State gas price. If State price goes up by 1.2% from my purchased price, I will set my price to +1% of my purchased price.

Here is a python code but it is very clunky, and if gas price moves up by 20%, then I have to write my_priceX up to 20 times. Is there a more elegant solution?

```
my_price1 = last_gas_price["price"]*1.01 
my_price2 = last_gas_price["price"]*1.02 
my_price3 = last_gas_price["price"]*1.03 
my_price4 = last_gas_price["price"]*1.04  
my_price5 = last_gas_price["price"]*1.05 

if last_gas_price > my_price1:
    adj_price(price = my_price1)

if last_gas_price > my_price2:
    adj_price(price = my_price2)

if last_gas_price > my_price3:
    adj_price(price = my_price3)

if last_gas_price > my_price4:
    adj_price(price = my_price4)

if last_gas_price > my_price5:
    adj_price(price = my_price5)
```

Comment: What is `last_gas_price`? It's a dictionary when you do `last_gas_price["price"]`, but it seems to be a number when you do `if last_gas_price > my_price1:`

Comment: Do you really need to call `adj_price()` for each price increment? Can't you just find the maximum increment below `last_gas_price` and call it once with that value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop over the multipliers:

```
for multiplier in (1.01, 1.02, 1.03, 1.04, 1.05):
    if last_gas_price > last_gas_price["price"]*multiplier:
        adj_price(price=last_gas_price["price"]*multiplier)
```

With [3.8+'s walrus operator](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/) you can avoid redoing the multiplication if you really care:

```
for multiplier in (1.01, 1.02, 1.03, 1.04, 1.05):
    if last_gas_price > (myprice := last_gas_price["price"]*multiplier):
        adj_price(price=myprice)
```

If you only need to run `adj_price` once, for the *highest* passing multiplier, run the loop in reverse and `break` when you get a hit:

```
for multiplier in (1.05, 1.04, 1.03, 1.02, 1.01):  # Reversed multipliers
    if last_gas_price > (myprice := last_gas_price["price"]*multiplier):
        adj_price(price=myprice)
        break  # Found highest passing multiplier and adjusted, now we're done
```

Note: The code you provided is clearly wrong (`last_gas_price` is a `dict` initially, then apparently a scalar, probably `float`, later). This new code replicates that mistake. You'd need to adjust the variable names used to separate the `dict` usage from the non-`dict` usage appropriately.

Comment: @Alex: You're welcome. If it solves your problem completely, you can click the checkmark next to the answer to mark it as accepted; it makes it clear to others that you consider the problem solved (where there are multiple answers that solve the problem, you give the check mark to whichever one solves the problem "best", by whatever metric you choose).

Answer (score -1):

OK, This situation as I see is pretty disordered, and as ifs are increazing per my_prize, use a for loop so you say as prize increases, set it as is it.

Comment: Don't just describe, show your suggested code. It sounds like it will be the same as ShadowRanger's answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).